# How to create a folder using mkdir on username of a user?

Tags: php, mkdir

I want to get a folder created on username of user logged in and then make that folder upload path for files. Can't find a way to do that. Tried something like this but failed. I get a error for mkdir line.

> syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

```
$username=$_SESIION['user'];
mkdir('./uploads/images/'.$username, 0777);
$upload_path = "./uploads/images/".$username;
```

Comment: issue at here need to add '/'
mkdir('./uploads/images/'.$username, 0777);
upload_path = "./uploads/images/'.$username";

Comment: @RakeshSojitra thanks i updated my code but now i have error

Comment: you need /uploads/images/ folder already created in your directory with full 777 permission.

Comment: its $upload_path not only upload_path and $upload_path = "./uploads/images/".$username;

Comment: @RakeshSojitra sorry bro that was typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
$username=$_SESIION['user'];
mkdir("./uploads/images/$username", 0777, true);
$upload_path = "./uploads/images/$username";
```

You should also set '`recursive`' flag '`true`' as third argument in `mkdir()` function.

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: it wont work as upload_path is a variable and should have '$' as a prefix

Comment: @SaurabhSinha: Yes brother my mistake I forgot '$'. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `mkdir()` to recursive to true by adding `true` as the third argument.

```
mkdir("./uploads/images/" . $username, 0777, true);
$upload_path = "./uploads/images/" . $username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below:

```
$username=$_SESIION['user'];
mkdir('./uploads/images/'.$username, 0777);
$upload_path = "./uploads/images/".$username";
```

use dobule quote rather than single and the variable should start with a '$' sign for upload_path

secondly please check that you have folder path uploads/images